# What is output of following program?

Tags: c, pointers

```
    int main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        int *p = &i;
        foo(&p);
        printf ("%d ", *p);
        printf ("%d ", *p);
    }

    void foo(int **const p)
    {
        int j = 11;
        *p = &j;
        //Printing the vlue
        printf("%d ", **p);
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a compiler?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the getting the output of a program without using a compiler.

Comment: Get a pen and a paper, draw things and you'll get the answer. To verify it, run your code.

Comment: The output is undefined, as in invoking undefined behaviour. You're creating pointers to a stack variable and after that returning, leaving the variable to be overwritten.

Comment: http://codepad.org/mV6hG4qR

Comment: @Austin What of it? Program has UB.

Answer (score 1):

When `foo` returns, the pointer `p` in `main` points to a local variable that existed during the execution of `foo`. Since `foo` has ended, de-referencing that pointer invokes undefined behaviour. Therefore your program can output, or indeed do, anything.